# Android Studio - Error:Execution failed for task ':app: ... ase'duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zznq.class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, admob, build.gradle

When I compile my project it write:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
>    com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/google/android/gms/internal/zznq.class

where is problem? I added to dependencies AdMob compile.

```
 dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
        compile project(':BaseGameUtils2')
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Thank you for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Replace `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'` with `apply plugin: ' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'`

The problem is that you have duplicate google service dependencies.

Comment: I doesn't work. It write: Error:(31, 0) Could not get unknown property 'compile' for project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.